# Running AngularJS on Ubuntu Linux with global environment variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, linux, ubuntu

On Windows for my AngularJS applications I had been using a file

env.js

Inside the file is global variable reference

```
(function (global) {
   window.__env = window.__env || {};
   window.__env.apiUrl = "http://10.100.40.52:3500"; //"http://localhost:3500";  
   window.__env.apiBase = "/api/";
   window.__env.jsonTest = 0;
}(this));
```

Then in app.js

```
var env = {};

if (window) {
    Object.assign(env, window.__env);
}

app.constant("$env", env);  // env.js  use in service/factories
```

So then in services and controllers I would using inject `$env`

ON windows, this works great,  but now that I'm moving to Linux Ubuntu should I assume this will not work?

**What is the Linux replacement for this?**

Comment: In your code, I see nothing that is specific to Windows or Linux. Maybe the file aren't imported in the same order as when you were on Windows. As I can see your file env.js must be imported before your file app.js, does it?

Comment: window  ,  that works on Linux?       I guess I assumed  "windows os"   ...

Comment: Yes I meant Windows OS. Can you provide any errors or write what breaks ?